# How to add class to target nodes in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to make the external link background yellow by adding `class = 'external'` to them, I don't know how to achieve that. Could someone please help? How to identify external link and how to add class to them accordingly?

```
<style>
.external { background-color: yellow }
</style>
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="/tutorial">/tutorial.html</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="ftp://ftp.com/file.zip">ftp://ftp.com/file.zip</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://nodejs.org">http://nodejs.org</a></li>
</ul>
```

The result should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach:

```js
// use Array.prototype.forEach to iterate over the elements returned by
// document.querySelectorAll('li a'):
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('li a'), function (aElem) {
  // if the hostname of the <a> element is not the same as the hostname of
  // of the current window:
  if (aElem.hostname !== window.location.hostname) {
    // we can add the 'external' class-name to the element's classList:
    aElem.classList.add('external');
  }
});
```

```css
.external {
  background-color: #ffa;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="/tutorial">/tutorial.html</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="ftp://ftp.com/file.zip">ftp://ftp.com/file.zip</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://nodejs.org">http://nodejs.org</a></li>
</ul>
```

Slightly more concisely, we could skip the `if (...)` and simply use `classList.toggle(classname, boolean)` in the `forEach()`:

```js
// use Array.prototype.forEach to iterate over the elements returned by
// document.querySelectorAll('li a'):
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('li a'), function (aElem) {
  // if the switch ('aElem.hostname !== window.location.hostname') evaluates to
  // true: we add the supplied classname, if it's
  // false: we remove the classname:
  aElem.classList.toggle('external', aElem.hostname !== window.location.hostname);
});
```

```css
.external {
  background-color: #ffa;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="/tutorial">/tutorial.html</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="ftp://ftp.com/file.zip">ftp://ftp.com/file.zip</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://nodejs.org">http://nodejs.org</a></li>
</ul>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`UrlUtils.hostname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.hostname).

Comment: Valid approach. But you could make it even shorter by using `[].forEach.call(...)` and `aElem.classList.toggle('external', (aElem.hostname !== window.location.hostname));`

Comment: True, but using `[].forEach.call()` initialises a new Array (which seems redundant, for the sake of saving a few characters); as for the use of `toggle()`? That was mere seconds away from being added (I tend to start with simple/obvious and add (slightly more...) complex answers in edits) :)

Comment: Yes. The purpose wasn't at all to judge your approach. Just offered some more ideas to evaluate. But appreciated and upvoted :).

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you can use CSS3 attribute selectors:

```css
a[href^="http://"],
a[href^="ftp://"],
a[href^="https://"],
a[href^="//"]
{
    background: yellow;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/368ghbh7/4/

See more: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Answer (score -1):

You need to use:

1. `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` in order to retrieve all the tags a in your page
2. iterate over them and set the `.className = "external"` of each tag you want to change calss

Here's the complete snippet:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for ( var i = 0; i < els.length; ++i ) 
    if ( i !== 2 )
    els[i].className = "external";
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ppzrLrLg/

Comment: Bear in mind that this approach will replace *all* pre-existing class-names with `'external'`; you may want to use `els[i].className += ' external';` to append the class-name, and thereby preserve other class-names.